# How to deal with duplicate records in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table with records as below image

[image: Student Table]

I have to maintain the replica of student ABC as shown below, for each student in each process can contain only one active row. What is the best way to stop duplicates for every student entry from db end.
how i manage uniqueness of active row.

How to check new INSERTS to prevent future duplicates.

Comment: There are no duplicate records here. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. There are thousands of examples of how to find duplicates across SO and the rest of the internet. None of your rows are actually duplicates in the sample posted. Perhaps if you could explain what you are trying to do we can help.

Comment: I think OP needs to check new INSERTS to prevent future duplicates.   Not remove dupes from existing data.

Comment: how i implement a unique key to check unique active row

Comment: @@Tab Alleman you are absolutely right catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maintain the uniqueness by using a unique filtered index:

```
create unique index unq_table_name_processid_filtered
    on table(name, processid) where IsActive = 'true';
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) is the documentation on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
create unique index unq_table_name_processid_filtered on table(name, processid) where IsActive = 1;
```

1 for bit type true

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the details of your solution? Explain what you did and how this is supposed to fix the problem. Otherwise, your answer might get deleted due to poor quality.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a CHECK constraint that calls a UDF.

You could also manage this with a TRIGGER.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
 WITH CTE 
 AS
    (
    SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orgName ORDER BY orgName DESC)
    FROM organizations 
    )
    select * 
    from CTE 
    where RN>1
```

Comment: . . How is this supposed to *maintain* the uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Unique index with filter can solve the issue

it is also known as filtered index

```
create unique index unq_table_filtered_IX
    on table(columns) where condition;
```